# Rails 5.1 with Capybara using assert_select to find a string

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am finding it very difficult to determine the syntax for assert_select in a system test for an exercise in Agile Web Development in Rails 5.1.  Whatever I try, I cannot locate the webpage element which contains the string I am searching for.

The HTML code as shown in the inspector is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pragprog Books Online Store</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token"         content="3FpWTUujgCw2iIsY9AjcvLuEd+SPVFT/zmlXfJKqETL8RJymxmnu1Moaqsz7hfhsnSToYDKBhzqk7ohzFzY6kg==" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="main">
      <img alt="The Pragmatic Bookshelf" src="/assets/logo-a    8906fb6c933f00883d2ad0385ae52201c0e1d1f9235c37f4a5762f02ad80936.svg" />
      <h1></h1>
    </header>
    <section class="content">
      <nav class="side_nav">

        <div id="cart" class="carts">


        </div>

        <ul>
          <li><b href="/">Today is Mon 09 Jul 2018</b>
          <c href="/">12:31 pm</c></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
          <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <main class='products'>
        <p id="notice">Product was successfully updated.</p>
```

The line I want is the last line of this code.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
assert_select 'body', text: "Product was successfully updated."

assert_select 'nav.main.products.notice', text: "Product was successfully updated."

assert_select "#notice"

assert_select "#notice", "Product was successfully updated."

page.find_field('notice' text: "Product was successfully updated")

assert_select "notice"

assert_select ‘id.notice’

assert_select "body", {:text=>"Product was successfully updated."}, "Nope!"

assert_select "body", "Product was successfully updated."

assert_select "body", {:text=>"Product was successfully updated."}

expect(page).to have_css("#notice", text: "Product was successfully updated.")

assert_text "Product was successfully created."

assert page.has_selector?("div#main", text: 'Product was successfully created')

assert_select '#notice'

assert_text "successfully"

assert select "div#notice", "Product was successfully created."

assert page.has_selector?(id="notice")
```

The error I get is always along the same lines:

```
Failure:
ProductsTest#test_creating_a_Product [/Users/Srjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.2.1/lib/capybara/minitest.rb:105]:
expected to find visible select box "body" with text "Product was successfully updated." that is not disabled but there were no matches
```

Any clues?

/s

Answer (score 1):

From the docs linked to `assert_select` - "Checks if the page or current node has a select field..."  - This tells you that it works with `<select>` elements which you don't have in this HTML so it's never going to work.

If you're trying to verify the text is contained within the an element with an id of 'notice' then what should work for you is

```
assert_css('#notice', text: 'Product was successfully updated.')
```

which is just short for

```
assert_selector(:css, '#notice', text: 'Product was successfully updated.'  # Note selector - not select
```